How to check PSS memory usage for a systemservice in Android
To get the  PSS memory usage 'top' or 'dumpsys meminfo' does not work for an individual system service (eg com.android.server.wifi.WifiService) in Android that I am aware of.
Is there a command or way to get PSS memory usage for system service?
I tried top and dumpsys meminfo. Gives results only for processes.
I also tried dumpsys meminfo system. Gives total system service memory usage which does not help much.
